# How to load data from local JSON to the labels in table view using swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, uitableview

Have some problem with loading data from JSON to my labels in table view cell. Data is working, I can print it, but when I trying to load, it shows an error "Index out of range" or only empty table view. Here is my model and function to load JSON in view controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct BeatData: Decodable {
    let data: [BeatPackData]
}

struct BeatPackData: Decodable {
    let loops: [Loop]
    let beatloops: [BeatLoop]
}

struct BeatLoop: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let instrument: String
    let songName: String
    let producer: String
}

struct Loop: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let producer: String
    let count: String
    let genre: String
}

public class DataLoader {
        @Published var beatLoops = [BeatLoop]()

        init() {
            parseJSON()
        }
        //        loadLoops()
        //    }
        //

        func parseJSON() {
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json") else {
                print("\n-------> bundle path error")
                return
            }
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        

do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(BeatData.self, from: jsonData)
    self.brainLoops = response.data.beatloops
    for beatPackData in response.data {
        self.beatLoops.append(contentsOf: beatPackData.beatloops)
            
        }
                print("\n-------> response: \(response)")
            }
            catch {
                print("\n====> error: \(error)" )
            }
            return
        }
    }
}
```

On the top of view controller, I've created an instance: `let dataNew = DataLoader()`
Here is my table view methods:

```
extension BeatPackViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataNew.beatLoops.count
//        return dataNew.beatLoops.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CustomLoopsCell = beatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstLoopCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomLoopsCell
//        gettingSongName()
        
        cell.loopNameLabel.text = dataNew.beatLoops[indexPath.row].name
        cell.producerLabel.text = dataNew.beatLoops[indexPath.row].producer
        cell.instrumentLabel.text = dataNew.beatLoops[indexPath.row].instrument
        
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.selectionStyle = .none        
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
//        cell.playButtonOutlet.tag = indexPath.row
        
        if let playingCell = currentPlayingIndex, playingCell == indexPath.row {
            cell.playButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pause.png"), for:
                                            .normal)
        } else {
            cell.playButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "playBtn.png"), for:
                                            .normal)
        }
    return cell
}
```

Also here is my JSON file:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "beatloops": [
                {
                    "name" : "Alien",
                    "instrument" :"Arp",
                    "songName" : "alienarpjason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Big Brake",
                    "instrument" :"Drums",
                    "songName" : "BigBrake_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Bongo Beats",
                    "instrument" :"Drums",
                    "songName" : "BongoBeats_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Dreaming",
                    "instrument" :"Keys",
                    "songName" : "Dreaming_Keys_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Funky Groove",
                    "instrument" :"Bass",
                    "songName" : "FunkyGroove_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Futurist",
                    "instrument" :"Arp",
                    "songName" : "Futurist_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Hoping for change",
                    "instrument" :"Arp",
                    "songName" : "HopingForChange_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Manic",
                    "instrument" :"Bass",
                    "songName" : "Manic_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Sassy",
                    "instrument" :"Drums",
                    "songName" : "Sassy_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Serious",
                    "instrument" :"Arp",
                    "songName" : "Serious_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Stable Bricks",
                    "instrument" :"Bass",
                    "songName" : "StableBrick_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Thump",
                    "instrument" :"Drums",
                    "songName" : "Thump_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Tropic",
                    "instrument" :"Drums",
                    "songName" : "TropicVibe_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                }
            ],
            "loops": [
                {
                    "name": "Away we go",
                    "producer": "Tubular Kingz",
                    "count": "28",
                    "genre": "Lo-fi Hip Hop"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "producer": "Testing",
                    "count": "25",
                    "genre": "Lo-fi"
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

My view controller:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class BeatPackViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var beatView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var beatTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var coverImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var looppackNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var producerNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButtonLabel: UIButton!
    
    var allButtons: [UIButton] = []
    
    var currentPlayingIndex : Int?

//    let data = [BeatData]()


    let dataNew = DataLoader().beatLoops
    
    var songs: [String] = []
    
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    
//MARK: - SONG METHODS

    func playLoop(songName: String) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: songName, withExtension: ".mp3")  // you should check it for errors
        audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)  // of course you should catch the error and deal with it...
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    
    func gettingSongName() {
        let folderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath!)
        
        do {
            let songPath = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
            
            for song in songPath {
                var mySong = song.absoluteString
                
                if mySong.contains(".mp3") {
                    let findString = mySong.components(separatedBy: "/")
                    mySong = findString[findString.count - 1]
                    mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ")
                    mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: ".mp3", with: "")
                    songs.append(mySong)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var backButtonView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var baxkButtonView: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        beatTableView.delegate = self
        beatTableView.dataSource = self
//        parseJSON()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = SettingsService.sharedService.backgroundColor
        coverImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        coverImage.layer.shadowRadius = 7
        coverImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        coverImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
        coverImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        coverImage.clipsToBounds = true
        gettingSongName()
        
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.baxkButtonView)
        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        visualEffectView.frame = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -30).offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -20))!
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
//        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
//        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
        
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
//        let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.backButton)
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
//        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem
        //        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(self.back(sender:))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    }
    @objc func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        print("done")
    }
    
    
    
}

//MARK: TABLEVIEW DATASOURCE, DELEGATE METHODS

extension BeatPackViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataNew.count
//        return dataNew.beatLoops.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CustomLoopsCell = beatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstLoopCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomLoopsCell
//        gettingSongName()
        cell.loopNameLabel.text = dataNew[indexPath.row].name
        
//        cell.loopNameLabel.text = dataNew.beatLoops[indexPath.row].name
//        cell.producerLabel.text = dataNew.beatLoops[indexPath.row].producer
//        cell.instrumentLabel.text = dataNew.beatLoops[indexPath.row].instrument
        
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.selectionStyle = .none        
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
//        cell.playButtonOutlet.tag = indexPath.row
        
        if let playingCell = currentPlayingIndex, playingCell == indexPath.row {
            cell.playButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pause.png"), for:
                                            .normal)
        } else {
            cell.playButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "playBtn.png"), for:
                                            .normal)
        }
    return cell
}
//MARK: - Button Check
    
    func btnUseTap(cell: CustomLoopsCell) {
        
        let indexPath = self.beatTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        if currentPlayingIndex == cell.tag {
            audioPlayer.pause()
            currentPlayingIndex = nil
        } else { //IF PAUSE BUTTON
            playLoop(songName: songs[cell.tag])
            currentPlayingIndex = cell.tag
        }
        beatTableView.reloadData()
        //        playSong(index: indexPath!.row)
        print("Done")
    }
```

Comment: You have to assign `response` in `parseJSON` to the data source array. At the moment you print it and then throw it away.

Comment: How to make it, could you show please?

Comment: `self.beatLoops = response.data.beatloops`. And it's unclear how the model and table view are connected.

Comment: ====> error: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: ??? The JSON in the question and the corresponding structs do match. This error must not occur.

Comment: Don't know, I've just put this which you wrote and got an error

Comment: Just inserting the line cannot cause the error. You should add more information how you access the class in the view controller. And is this question about UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: UIKit. I have a DataLoader.swift file. There I have this code. In the view controller I have an instance to data loader, check I've update the post

Comment: Note:  to add the response beatloops to your DataLoader beatloops, add this after "let response = ...":
 
 `for beatPackData in response.data {
     self.beatLoops.append(contentsOf: beatPackData.beatloops)
 }`

Comment: Got an error: For-in loop requires 'BeatPackViewController.BeatPackData' to conform to 'Sequence'

Comment: my note is to add that code to the "class DataLoader" parseJSON function, not the BeatPackViewController.

Comment: Now put in model file in function and got this: For-in loop requires 'BeatPackData' to conform to 'Sequence'

Comment: can you edit your question and show where you have put this code, and any other changes you have made.

Comment: Check, I've edited

Comment: Data is printed good, but can't load it to the labels, it didn't shows on the row

Comment: ha I see, you have completely changed your data model, but did not tell us. Did you change the json data as well? What is "brainLoops"?

Comment: I've changed only name and take out one array to try with only one array. In JSON file I didn't change nothing

Comment: your "new" data structure will not work. data is an array in your json, but it is not an array in your "BeatData", unless you have changed the json data. Your old structure was good.

Comment: I've changed it back, data is printing. Some problem with loading data to labels and numberofrowsinsection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are continuously editing and changing the data, the latest version messed everything up.
This is a tested working version, please read and copy/paste the data carefully.

This is the JSON (a bit shortened)

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "beatloops": [
            {
                "name" : "Alien",
                "instrument" :"Arp",
                "songName" : "alienarpjason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Big Brake",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "BigBrake_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Bongo Beats",
                "instrument" :"Drums",
                "songName" : "BongoBeats_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
            }
        ],
        "loops": [
            {
                "name": "Away we go",
                "producer": "Tubular Kingz",
                "count": "28",
                "genre": "Lo-fi Hip Hop"
            },
            {
                "name": "Test",
                "producer": "Testing",
                "count": "25",
                "genre": "Lo-fi"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The corresponding structs are

```
struct BeatData: Decodable {
    let data: BeatPackData
}

struct BeatPackData: Decodable {
    let loops: [Loop]
    let beatloops: [BeatLoop]
}

struct BeatLoop: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let instrument: String
    let songName: String
    let producer: String
}

struct Loop: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let producer: String
    let count: String
    let genre: String
}
```

The `@Publisher` attribute makes no sense without Combine, replace the class with the following, the parser returns the `BeatPackData` object or `nil` in case of an error

```
public class DataLoader {
    
    func parseJSON() -> BeatPackData? {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json") else {
            print("\n-------> bundle path error")
            return nil
        }
        
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(BeatData.self, from: jsonData)
            print("\n-------> response: \(response)")
            return response.data
        }
        catch {
            print("\n====> error: \(error)" )
            return nil
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is the relevant code in the view controller

```
class BeatPackViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var beatTableView: UITableView!
    
    var loops = [Loop]()
    var beatLoops = [BeatLoop]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let loader = DataLoader()
        guard let data = loader.parseJSON() else { return }
        loops = data.loops
        beatLoops = data.beatloops
        beatTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension BeatPackViewController : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return beatLoops.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CustomLoopsCell = beatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstLoopCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomLoopsCell
        let beatLoop = beatLoops[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.loopNameLabel.text = beatLoop.name
        cell.producerLabel.text = beatLoop.producer
        cell.instrumentLabel.text = beatLoop.instrument
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks to you, that you help me with this task, because it's hard for me now.. Now I've got printed data in table view, but when try to make more than 3 it's shows: ====> error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "beatloops", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 3", intValue: 3)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"name\", intValue: nil) (\"name\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Hey, now all is working! Thanks a lot for you, I've fixed one line and now can populate the table view. So I can use now the second array of the JSON file in another view controller to make the same population to the labels?

Comment: Yes, you can use the second array or create a new instance of `DataLoader` and parse the data again.

Answer (score 0):

In the `viewDidLoad()` function of your view controller, make sure you run your dataLoader to fetch the data.

After the data is loaded in the data loader, you need to send a message to the view controller saying data is ready to display.

You can do this through:

- a protocol/delegate
- using a closure as a completion handler
- setting up an observer for the `@Published` attribute you have
- (if you're on the iOS 15 beta) using async/await
  There are lots of ways to do this part, and I can explain in more detail if you pick one.

Once you have the data, run `reloadData()` on the table view.

Comment: But how to run this, because it is a class. When I run an app, I can see all data printed, but it don't load to labels